# I am trying to insert data in Access DB as per selection

Tags: c#

Please find attached, my code which i have written, but when it runs and when i enter data in form n click on Submit it gives me error in `"Command.executenonquery statement"`..

It displays `Invalid Operation exception was mishandled`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\databses\electric_data.accdb";
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Electric_Data (Asset_Id,Asset_Name,Emp_Id,Type_of_Asset,Actual_Start_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
                command.Parameters.Add("@Asset_Id", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox1.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Asset_Name", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = textBox2.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Type_of_Asset", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox3.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Id", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = textBox4.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Actual_Start_date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Open();
                command.Connection = conn;

                MessageBox.Show("Entry Registered Successfully.");
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\databses\electric_data.accdb";
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Electric_Data (Asset_Id,Asset_Name,Emp_Id,Type_of_Asset,Actual_end_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
                command.Parameters.Add("@Asset_Id", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox1.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Asset_Name", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = textBox2.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Id", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox3.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Type_of_Asset", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox4.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Actual_end_date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Open();
                command.Connection = conn;

                MessageBox.Show("Entry Registered Successfully.");
            }

            else if (radioButton1.Checked == false && radioButton2.Checked == false)
                MessageBox.Show("Check Work_Start or Work_Complete option for successful Entry.");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) you intentionally changed parameter name to "?" ?

Comment: yesw so that multiples data can be used for inputting

Comment: You can't do that. It should have the parameter name whatever you are adding. Also open connection before executing the query.

Answer (score 1):

You have gotten the conn.Open() in the wrong place. Try -->

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\databses\electric_data.accdb";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Electric_Data (Asset_Id,Asset_Name,Emp_Id,Type_of_Asset,Actual_Start_date) VALUES (@Asset_Id,@Asset_Name,@Emp_Id,@Type_of_Asset,@Actual_end_date)";   
command.Parameters.Add("@Asset_Id", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Asset_Name", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = textBox2.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Emp_Id", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox3.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Type_of_Asset", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox4.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Actual_end_date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;

// Open connection and assign to command
conn.Open();
command.Connection = conn;

// Execute non-query command
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

As an aside:

1. you need to not duplicate conn strings, column names etc in your code. Makes for a nightmare to maintain and debug.
2. You need to add in try...catch exception handling - what if the DB doesn't open for some reason.

EDIT: command.CommandText as wrong also per answer by other learned people.

Comment: It gave  anew error "{"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: Are Asset_Id,Asset_Name,Emp_Id,Type_of_Asset all varchar(20) / is Actual_end_date a date in your DB?

Answer (score 0):

Your command text is completely wrong.Change question marks with your parameter names:

```
 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Electric_Data (Asset_Id,Asset_Name,Emp_Id,Type_of_Asset,Actual_Start_date) VALUES (@Asset_Id,@Asset_Name,@Emp_Id,@Type_of_Asset,@Actual_end_date)";
```

You are open your connection after your ExecuteNonQuery, first open your connection,then execute your query

```
conn.Open();
command.Connection = conn;    
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I tried that Still same error "{"ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized."}"

Answer (score 0):

Try this insert query.Remove `?,?,?,?`

```
 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Electric_Data (Asset_Id,Asset_Name,Emp_Id,Type_of_Asset,Actual_Start_date) VALUES (@Asset_Id,@Asset_Name,@Emp_Id,@Type_of_Asset,@Actual_end_date)";
```

check the datatypes of your table-columns